# Create snapshots of multiple EBS volumes using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-ebs

I am trying to create snapshots of certain EBS volumes based on tags in a particular AWS region using Terraform. 
I have tried filtering EBS volumes based on Tags. I can get a clear output of EBS volume id when only one tag value is specified in the filter attribute but for more than one values, i get the following error:

> data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume: data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume: Your
>   query returned more than one result. Please try a more specific search
>   criteria, or set `most_recent` attribute to true.

Below is my terraform template:

```
data "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["EBS1","EBS2","EBS3"]
  }
}
output "ebs_volume_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.id}"
}

resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "ebs_volume" {
  volume_id = "${data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.id}"
}
```

Is there a clear way to create snapshots of multiple EBS volumes using any kind of looping statement in terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`count` meta parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count) to loop over lists, creating multiple resources or data sources.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
variable "ebs_volumes" {
  default = [
    "EBS1",
    "EBS2",
    "EBS3",
  ]
}

data "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  count = "${length(var.ebs_volumes)}"

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.ebs_volumes[count.index]}"]
  }
}

output "ebs_volume_ids" {
  value = ["${data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.*.id}"]
}

resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "ebs_volume" {
  count     = "${length(var.ebs_volumes)}"
  volume_id = "${data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.*.id[count.index]}"
}
```

Comment: Did you forgot to put quotation marks in filter values attribute??
["${var.ebs_volumes[count.index]}"]. Otherwise, this worked like a charm. Thanks!!